# Static Library Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm trying to build the libpng library into a static library on Android, but it's not working! Every time I try to build it, it doesn't do anything. Below is the android make file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS :=

LOCAL_MODULE := libpng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=\
png.c \
pngerror.c \
pngget.c \
pngmem.c \
pngpread.c \
pngread.c \
pngrio.c \
pngrtran.c \
pngrutil.c \
pngset.c \
pngtrans.c \
pngwio.c \
pngwrite.c \
pngwtran.c \
pngwutil.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

And if I change the last line to 
     include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

it builds correctly! Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In the same directory make an `Application.mk` file and enter the line:

```
APP_MODULES := your-android-library-as-defined-in-Android.mk
```